# stand alone software to analyze har files on a windows platform

Tags: google-chrome, har

I need to be able to analyze a captured har using a standalone program.
I know there are online tools that are easy to use but we need to be able to run it somewhere that there is no internet connection. So I need a windows based tool that will allow us to see message timings and message data and responses,etc.
I looked into several but none of them were able to work how I wanted.
Any suggestions??
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler can be used to view these files as well. Goto File > Import Session > HttpArchive

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com)? It has a stand-alone viewer that can open HAR files and display detailed timings, requests and responses.

** DISCLAIMER: Posted by Neumetrix Limited, the makers of HttpWatch